# Find the highest value in a nested array, and then log the pair (number and a string)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I am working through a JavaScript course on Udemy, and while I have already solved this challenge with a basic if/else if/else code block, I am trying to do it in a more complicated way.

The challenge is to take the scores of 3 basketball games amongst 3 players, find the average of each, then determine who had the highest average score. Here is what I have:

```
const johnTeamScores = [89, 120, 103];
const mikeTeamScores = [116, 94, 123];
const maryTeamScores = [97, 134, 108];

function getAverageScore(array, player) {
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    total += array[i];
  }

  const average = total / array.length;
  console.log(`The average score for ${player}'s team is: ${average}`);

  const playerName = (arguments[1]); // Get passed in player name
  console.log(playerName);

  return [average, playerName];
}

const johnTeamAverage = getAverageScore(johnTeamScores, 'John');
const mikeTeamAverage = getAverageScore(mikeTeamScores, 'Mike');
const maryTeamAverage = getAverageScore(maryTeamScores, 'Mary');

const finalArray = [];
finalArray.push(johnTeamAverage, mikeTeamAverage, maryTeamAverage);
console.log(finalArray);
```

In the console for `finalArray`, I see this:

[image]

I found this code block here on Stack Overflow which helped me find the winning pair:

```
const winingPair = finalArray.reduce((max, arr) => {
  return max[0] >= arr[0] ? max : arr;
});
```

So when I log this:

```
console.log(`The highest average score was ${winingPair[0]}, which was done by ${winingPair[1]}'s team.`);
```

I get the correct statement of `The highest average score was 113, which was done by Mary's team.`

Great! Buy my question is regarding how the reduce method found this result. I am still learning these higher order array methods, so I don't want to simply copy and paste this and walk away. I want to understand what is going on here. So if someone is willing to give a brief explanation in plain English on how this result was obtained, that would be most helpful and appreciated. I know that is using the ternary operator, but how it is using it is leaving me a bit confused. Thank you!

Also I am aware this does not account for a tie in average scores, I am just looking to find the highest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method. The `reduce` method will coint all sum and then just divide this sum by `length` of array:

```
const getAverage = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((a, c)=> a+=c, 0) / arr.length;
}
```

The whole example could be look like this:

```js
const johnTeamScores = [89, 120, 103];
const mikeTeamScores = [116, 94, 123];
const maryTeamScores = [97, 134, 108];

const getAverage = (arr, name) => {
    return [(arr.reduce((a, c)=> a+=c, 0) / arr.length), name];
}

 const allPlayers = [getAverage(johnTeamScores, 'John'), 
 getAverage(mikeTeamScores, 'Mike'), getAverage(maryTeamScores, 'Mary')];

 const getMax = (arr) => {
     return arr.reduce((max, arr)=> max[0] >= arr[0] ? max : arr);
 }

 console.log(getMax(allPlayers))
```

How this code works?

```
const winingPair = finalArray.reduce((max, arr) => {
  return max[0] >= arr[0] ? max : arr;
});
```

The signature of `reduce` method looks like this:

```
arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue[, index[, array]] )[, initialValue])
```

However, your signature looks like this:

```
 arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue))
```

- So we see that that there is no `initial value` in signature. So if no `initialValue` is supplied, [the first element in the array will be used and skipped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- `reduce` works like a simple loop, it iterates over array elements, but in our case `reduce` returns value which has greater value. How this code return greater value? This code makes comparison and return greater value: `return max[0] >= arr[0] ? max : arr;`

It is better to debug and more becomes clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Reduce will iterate over your array of tuples (pairs of score and name). The function that reduce accepts is a function that as a first parameter is called accumulator, it is basically a returned value from previous iteration (during first iteration it is equal to first element of the array and first element will not be invoked with callback, or if you provide a initial value it will be equal to initial value and first element will take part in iteration)

So going back to your question.

```
const winingPair = finalArray.reduce((max, arr) => {
  return max[0] >= arr[0] ? max : arr;
});
```

In first iteration max is a first element of your scores array. max[0] and arr[0] is actually a averages. You are returning the pair with greater average so it will be used in next iteration. In second iteration you are comparing winning score from first iteration with third score and again you will return the greater one.